# transfer video file to iphone from macbook over shared internet connection

Tags: macos, iphone, command-line, mojave

My iPhone is USB-connected to my macbook and my macbook has internet sharing turned on.

How can i send a video file from my macbook to the iphone using the command line?

Answer (score 1):

[Not a full answer; not re CLI] 
I don’t know if the transfer is possible in a useful manner, but look at iExplorer from Macroplant & especially its feature to [use device as USB drive](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer/mount-iphone-disk-mode-file-folder-access). Whatever limitations exist to this (e.g., no root directory access) would suggest to me that those limitations are fundamental to iOS.